# Clearing std :: string in while loop С++

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

I am creating a Thread which contains a While loop. It gets data 
 from the API site every iteration, checking the new data.

```
string data;
while (true) {
     data = get_contents ('http://example.com/');
     Sleep (300,000);
}
```

The problem is that the `string data` variable is not cleared. 
What i can you do with it?

PS: I was try this, but this is not working.

```
data.erase();
data.clear();
data.resize(0);
```

Comment: is that string a "std::string"???

Comment: As things stand, your question can't really be answered. What is the behavior you see, and what do you expect?

Comment: "variable is not cleared" What does it mean exactly? What did you expect to observe, and what did you actually observe?

Comment: Note that `'http://example.com/'` should be `"http://example.com/"`, i.e., with **double** quotes, not single quotes. And if `Sleep` takes one agreement, which seems likely, `Sleep(300,000)` is just a confusing way of writing `Sleep(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

refer to the doc [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear)

doing

```
data.clear();
```

is the correct way to go but re assigning a new value to the object `data` using the `= operator` is working as well.

---

on the other hand, [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) can be helpful when removing specified characters from the string.
while [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) is more to resizes the string to contain count characters.